# Chi square test of independence with year as a categorical variable?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, count-data, contingency-tables

I suppose that this is a very simple question, and I have just now recently started doing stats.

I am working on a dataset with count data relating to discontinuation/continuation of a specific injectable drug, and I created a contingency table that looked like this:

|  | Discontinued | Stayed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 2084 | 663 |
| 2019 | 1916 | 1207 |

I ran a Pearson's chi square test with Yates' continuity correction, which gave me a significant association. I ran Fisher's exact test to find out the odds ratio.

I have two questions. First, is it appropriate for me to use year as one of the categorical variables in a chi square test? If so, is it okay for me to interpret that "individuals in 2019 were nearly twice as likely to continue using the contraceptive after the first dose, compared to those in 2018?" I am not entirely sure how to interpret the results of this chi square test, or if chi square is the most appropriate test for this scenario. Here is what I ran in R:

```
tab <- matrix(c(2084,663,1916,1207)
              , ncol=2, nrow=2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('Discontinued', 'Stayed')
rownames(tab)<-c('2018','2019')
tab <- as.table(tab)
print(tab)
chisq.test(tab)
fisher.test(tab)
```

Results of the test

```
> chisq.test(tab)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  tab
X-squared = 141.14, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

> fisher.test(tab)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  tab
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.765474 2.221507
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
   1.97993
```

Comment: "individuals in 2019 were nearly twice as likely to continue using the contraceptive after the first dose, compared to those in 2018?" - to me that suggests relative risk rather than odds ratio.

Answer (score 2):

If you run logistic with glm, you get:

```
year <- c(rep("2018", 2084+663), rep("2019",1916+1207))
drug <- c(rep(0, 2084), rep(1, 663), rep(0, 1916), rep(1, 1207))

model <- glm(drug ~ year, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model)

exp(0.68317)
exp(confint(model))
```

where the two exp() functions are used to obtain the odds ratio and the  confidence interval for the odds ratio. The results are:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.14527    0.04459  -25.68   <2e-16 ***
year2019     0.68317    0.05778   11.82   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 7346.7  on 5869  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7203.2  on 5868  degrees of freedom
AIC: 7207.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> exp( 0.68317)
[1] 1.980145

> exp(confint(model))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
               2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.291319 0.3469683
year2019    1.768659 2.2182985
```

So "exactly" the same odds ratio and CI as you got with the Fisher exact test, like Peter Flom already said.

The confidence interval shows you that the null hyposthesis "oddsratio = 2" would not have to be rejected. However, I think you would not want to test such an explicit hypothesis about the true value of the oddsratio (in the population, say). The Fisher test gives you all you want, you can now say that the two odds values differ significantly, the one for 2019 "being about two as high". This final addition however only "descriptive", because as I said above, I think you would not like to really test that explicitly.

Comment: Agreed with most of your answer, but shouldn't OP just report the confidence interval, and refrain from saying anything like "being about two as high"? (or at least, mentioning that this kind of observation is applicable only to the sample, not to the population?). As OP question is about an injectable drug, it's likely that the point of the analysis is inference, not simple description of the sample (but I may be mistaken!).

Comment: @J-J-J Good point, one has to be careful with making such statement. On the other hand, this is quite a big sample. Still, a conclusion like "being about twice as high for these data" would be safer to say.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are only two years, a chi-square test is appropriate. Your specific test indicates that there is codependence: the "discontinued"/"stayed" status depends on the year.

You ask: "... is it okay for me to interpret that individuals in 2019 were nearly twice as likely to continue using the contraceptive after the first dose, compared to those in 2018?" No, it is not ok. To make those type of statements, you could run [logistic regression](http://stanfordphd.com/Logistic_Regression.html). It provides the researcher with odds, among other things.

Comment: Why wouldn't a chi-squared test be appropriate if there were more than two years?

Comment: It would be valid but not most powerful. When ordinal X is explored in connection with categorical Y, the ordinal nature of X has to be exploited to achieve highest discerning capability. X should not be "misunderstood" and viewed as categorical. Ex: there is information in the fact that 2019 comes in-between 2018 and 2020. Ignoring that is throwing power out of the window.

Comment: OP got the OR from Fisher's exact test. Why would he need to run logistic as well? Actually, in a 2x2 table, it's easy to get the OR by hand

Comment: @stans So, to clarify. I need to fit a logistic regression model to provide a significant OR, and and OR from a chi square is not sufficient enough.

Comment: Whenever one makes any prediction or assessment, one has to put a confidence interval around it. Logit, probit and similar models allow you to do that. Chi-square test doesn't. It is not enough to say: oh, look A seems to be bigger than B.

Comment: @stans OP's question already mentions a confidence interval for the odds ratio, look at the output of `fisher.test(tab)` at the end of the question.

Comment: @stans Re: the use of chi-square test if we had more than 2 years, it would entirely depends on why we're conducting the test; you don't necessarily want to treat the variable "year" as ordinal, depending on your research question. (Now, it would raise the question as to why we wouldn't want to treat "year" as ordinal, but we shouldn't automatically dismiss the possibility that treating it as ordinal might be irrelevant to the research question).

Comment: @J-J-J We are not discussing Fisher's test, which would be valid if rows and columns of the cross-table added up to fixed, pre-specified numbers. We are discussing chi-square test and alternatives. Please refer to my original post.

Comment: I'm not talking Fisher's test either. This is just that the `fisher`  function in R happens to provide odds ratio and confidence intervals, the same as provided by a logistic regression. I think this is all very confusing, and that your answer should acknowledge all the information provided in OP's question.

Comment: PS: I'm making these comments not necessarily to contradict the gist of the answer (in particular as I could learn some things in the process), but to help improving it, as I find it a bit terse and lacking further explanations that could be helpful to the OP and other readers. In other words, I think you could improve your answer if you gave a bit more details about the statements you're making.

Comment: @J-J-J Again please refer to my original post. My post was solely about addressing the chi-square test results of the OP and suggesting alternatives. And every sentence I wrote is correct. Please re-read... Sure, there are several methods to estimate odds and put confidence intervals around them. Logit, probit, CLT implication for percentages (related to Z-tests for proportions),... 

<tbc>